# Qual método é mais eficiente para escalar, usar um redis as a service ou redis em disco?

Tags: amazon-aws, redis

Tenho uma dúvida em relação à melhor abordagem para armazenamento de dados em cache utilizando o redis. Eu gostaria de usar um Redis as a Service como Amazon Elasti Cachi ou algum outro.

Porém eu fico em dúvida se a latência de rede que eu teria nas minhas buscas ao consultar através de uma conexão com uma máquina que está fora do meu cluster, prejudicaria demais a minha performance, a ponto de ser mais viável ter uma máquina dentro da minha VPC, para utilizar o Redis.

Alguém sabe me informar quão grande seria o gap de performance entre o I/O enviado por rede aberta vs I/O direto no disco local ou em um dentro de uma máquina da minha rede privada dentro da mesma região na Amazon?

Tendo em vista o ganho de performance, vale apena assumir a responsabilidade e os custos de gerenciar uma infraestrutura de redis? Ou é mais viável e prático utiliza-lo como um serviço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio disco é sempre mais rápido que rede, ainda mais se tiver que passar pela internet...
Se o volume de dados que você pretende usar não for muito grande, não haveria problemas em colocar o Redis em um outro host dentro da mesma rede, caso o volume seja grande, o melhor a fazer é utilizar ele local e "entupir" o host local de memória...

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo o redis na mesma rede, mas já tive problemas com o volume trafegado em rede com as chaves do redis. Esse problema eu resolvi utilizado o MessagePack para diminuir o tamanho dos dados(ao invés de utilizar o valor das chaves em json).
Para escalar o redis, utilizamos o twemProxy na frente de 3 servidores de redis, ele distribui as chaves entre os servidores e faz a consulta também, isso diminui a quantidade de hits em cada redis.